# Problemas con selectores aplicando hover

Tags: html5, css3, hover, selectores

estaba desarrollando un sitio web que tiene una tabla y en ella estoy aplicando un hover que cambie tanto el fondo como la letra.

El problema es que cuando realizo el hover con selectores en la ejecución se pasa el siguiente elemento de la tabla (tr) y no toma el primero.

Estuve revisando si tengo errores en la sintaxis pero estoy seguro de no tenerlos.

Consulté algunas paginas y sigo como loco con lo que me está mostrando el navegador.

[image: Foto del diseño final con el hover]

Dejo el enlace en codepen.io por si alguien me puede ayudar:

[Enlace CondePen.io](https://codepen.io/donCelis/pen/VXGOMo?editors=1100#0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estimado el selector `+` funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
div + p
```

el selector de arriba lo que hace es tomar un elemento `p` que esta inmediatamente después de un elemento `div`. Entonces en tu código css:

```
.tabla tbody tr:hover + tr td
```

lo que estas seleccionando aquí es, al hacer `hover` sobre una fila (tr), seleccionará todas las celdas de la fila siguiente. Creo que lo que quieres lograr es lo siguiente

```
.tabla tbody tr:hover td
```

Comment: Hola justo estaba realizando ese procedimiento, el asunto es que al hacer el hover no solo debe cambiar el fondo de la fila (tr) sino que también debe cambiar el color del texto (tr>.texto1), pero como el texto ya tiene un color diferente sin hover entonces la fila se queda sin texto al ser del mismo color.

Comment: en la respuesta di como sugerencia que cambiaras este selector `.tabla tbody tr:hover + tr td` por este otro `.tabla tbody tr:hover td`, cosa que yo mismo probé en tu codepen, aquí esta el link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVqMOR?editors=1100#0, ahora si el código original es diferente al que pusiste en el codepen creo que no puedo hacer mucho por ti

Comment: Gracias por el aporte.